# PX4 python dronekit, how to move a drone?

Tags: python, dronekit-python, dronekit, px4

I am using a quadrotor drone with PX4 1.8.0

I would like to write a python script which, according to some input, makes the drone moving in a specific direction (e.g. move 5 meters right,left,up down and so on) or making the drone moving to a specific gps location.
I need to do something very interactive, that is why missions do not suit my needs.

I have tried to use pymavlink/dronekit, both using specific commands like simple_goto()and using **message_factory** or **command_long_send** to directly send mavlink messages, but without results.I am also doing some tests on px4 gazebo simulator with the same result as on the drone

Only few commands work, for xample simple_takeoff() or command_long_send with MAV_CMD_NAV_TAKEOFF.

Does someone has an idea to make this drone move in an interactive way?
If you put some example or some guide it would be very appreciated   :)

Thank you very much

Comment: In which mode was you drone when you send these commands?

Comment: Dronekit doesn't officially support PX4 flight stack, you should Dronecode SDK for PX4 (https://sdk.dronecode.org/en/) or change your flight stack to ArduPilot.

Comment: I have tried all the modes: position,mission,hold,manual... all of them